# GuzzleHttp request text file without losing newlines

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm extracting data from the National Data Buoy Center (NDBC) and I was grabbing a text file of the [latest observations](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/latest_obs/41004.txt), which if I do this in JavaScript using AJAX I get the newlines and can parse the data readily, but using PHP (specifically GuzzleHttp) the newlines are lost and I can't expand on newlines to parse since they don't exist.

**Request**

```
$url = "http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/latest_obs/41004.txt";
$res = $this->httpClient->request('GET', $url);
```

**Response**

```
Station 41004 32° 30.0' N 79° 6.0' W 2:50 am EST 0750 GMT 01/26/18 Wind: ENE (60°), 15.5 kt Gust: 19.4 kt Seas: 3.6 ft Peak Period: 5 sec Pres: 30.54 Air Temp: 55.6 °F Water Temp: 70.2 °F Dew Point: 40.5 °F Wave Summary 2:40 am EST 0700 GMT 01/26/18 Swell: 1.3 ft Period: 10.0 sec Direction: SE Wind Wave: 3.3 ft Period: 5.0 sec Direction: ENE
```

Instead of like:

```
Station 41004
32° 30.0' N  79° 6.0' W

2:20 am EST
0720 GMT 01/26/18
Wind: ENE (60°), 13.6 kt
Gust: 19.4 kt
Pres: 30.54
Air Temp: 55.0 °F
Water Temp: 70.3 °F
Dew Point: 40.1 °F

Wave Summary
1:40 am EST
0600 GMT 01/26/18
Swell: 1.3 ft
Period: 8.3 sec
Direction: ENE
Wind Wave: 3.3 ft
Period: 4.3 sec
Direction: NE
```

Is there a way to maintain the newlines characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the new lines characters are there, at least for me, using this code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/latest_obs/41004.txt');
$result = utf8_encode($res->getBody()->getContents());
```

Printing the result, using any of the following methods:

```
echo '<pre>' . $result . '</pre>';
echo str_replace("\n", '<br>', $result);
```

Gives me this:

```
Station 41004
32° 30.0' N  79° 6.0' W

3:30 am EST
0830 GMT 01/26/18
Wind: ENE (60°), 15.5 kt
Gust: 19.4 kt
Pres: 30.54
Air Temp: 55.8 °F
Water Temp: 70.0 °F
Dew Point: 40.1 °F

Wave Summary
2:40 am EST
0700 GMT 01/26/18
Swell: 1.3 ft
Period: 10.0 sec
Direction: SE
Wind Wave: 3.3 ft
Period: 5.0 sec
Direction: ENE
Station 41004
32° 30.0' N 79° 6.0' W

3:30 am EST
0830 GMT 01/26/18
Wind: ENE (60°), 15.5 kt
Gust: 19.4 kt
Pres: 30.54
Air Temp: 55.8 °F
Water Temp: 70.0 °F
Dew Point: 40.1 °F

Wave Summary
2:40 am EST
0700 GMT 01/26/18
Swell: 1.3 ft
Period: 10.0 sec
Direction: SE
Wind Wave: 3.3 ft
Period: 5.0 sec
Direction: ENE
```

Comment: Sure does... I don't know what I was doing wrong to get that string, but using your example the response body contains the newlines :)

Comment: Figured out why yours works, but not mine.  I wasn't using double quotes around the newline character.  Doing `explode('\n', $result)` doesn't work you get an array with a single index containing the data as a single string, but doing `explode("\n", $result)` produces what I would expect.

Comment: Great, I forgot to reference that.